# Diff for POSIXct with units, like in difftime

Tags: r, apply, difftime

I have got a vector of POSIXct-data and want to calculate the difference between consecutive elements, like it is done by `diff`

e.g:

```
burst <- as.POSIXct(c("2016-11-07 17:20:52","2016-11-07 16:21:52", "2016-11-07 15:21:52", "2016-11-02 17:20:52","2016-11-02 16:21:52", "2016-11-02 15:21:52"))

conti <- as.POSIXct(c("2016-11-07 17:20:52","2016-11-06 17:20:52", "2016-11-05 17:20:52", "2016-11-04 17:20:52","2016-11-03 17:20:52", "2016-11-02 17:20:52"))

diff(burst)
diff(conti)
```

My problem is, that the units are not equal. I remember the function `difftime` which has got a parameter called `unit` but i am not able to construct a `apply`-function to get a simiral behaviour like in `diff`.

Comment: I didn't get your question; please share a sample output that you desire!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a way to enforce particular units with `diff` for POSIXt objects. In case there isn't, you can work directly with the numerical values and then set the class and the units attribute so that you'll still have a `difftime` object with a units attribute.

For example, to get differences in minutes:

```
burst.diff = diff(as.numeric(burst))/60
burst.diff = as.difftime(burst.diff, units="mins")

burst.diff
```

> ```
> Time differences in mins
> [1]   -59   -60 -7141   -59   -60
> ```

If you don't care about maintaining the object class or units, then you can just do:

```
burst.diff = diff(as.numeric(burst))/60
```

You could package this as a function. I'm not sure if this is the "right" way in terms of how I've handled class and attributes and I'd be interested to know if there are better ways to do this:

```
my_difftime = function(x, units="mins") {

  div = c("secs"=1, "mins"=60, "hours"=3600)

  if(is.na(match(units, names(div)))) {
    stop('Please specify either units as either "secs", "mins", or "hours"')
  } else {
    x = diff(as.numeric(x))/div[match(units, names(div))]
    as.difftime(x, units=units) 
  }
}

lapply(list(burst=burst, conti=conti), my_difftime, units="hours")
```

> ```
> $burst
> Time differences in hours
> [1]   -0.9833333   -1.0000000 -119.0166667   -0.9833333   -1.0000000
>
> $conti
> Time differences in hours
> [1] -24 -25 -24 -24 -24
> ```