# Successive time difference with POSIXct object in specific unit

Tags: r, posixct, date-difference, difftime

I'd like to compute the successive time differences of a vector of date-time (POSIXct object) in a specific unit in R.

With `difftime`, there is an argument `units` to force the units. But that's only for two date-times. For successive differences, I use `diff`. But with a POSIXct object, looks like there are some automatic choice of units depending on the values of differenciated dates.

```
date.posixct <- seq(as.POSIXct("2021/1/1"), as.POSIXct("2021/1/10"), "days")
> date.posixct
 [1] "2021-01-01 CET" "2021-01-02 CET" "2021-01-03 CET" "2021-01-04 CET"
 [5] "2021-01-05 CET" "2021-01-06 CET" "2021-01-07 CET" "2021-01-08 CET"
 [9] "2021-01-09 CET" "2021-01-10 CET"

diff(date.posixct)
Time differences in days
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Looks like if some differences are less than one day, it converts to seconds.

```
## Duplicate the first element to have a difference of 0.
date.posixct1 <- c(date.posixct[1], date.posixct)
> date.posixct1
 [1] "2021-01-01 CET" "2021-01-01 CET" "2021-01-02 CET" "2021-01-03 CET"
 [5] "2021-01-04 CET" "2021-01-05 CET" "2021-01-06 CET" "2021-01-07 CET"
 [9] "2021-01-08 CET" "2021-01-09 CET" "2021-01-10 CET"

diff(date.posixct1)
Time differences in secs
 [1]     0 86400 86400 86400 86400 86400 86400 86400 86400 86400
```

So how to use `diff` along with `difftime` to force the units? Help page of `difftime` says:

> There are methods for mean and sum (via the Summary group generic),
> and diff via diff.default building on the "difftime" method for
> arithmetic, notably -.

But not sure what it means.

Comment: `diff(unclass(date.posixct))` will always give seconds.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470389/diff-for-posixct-with-units-like-in-difftime

Comment: also, `mapply(difftime, tail(date.posixct1, -1), head(date.posixct1, -1), units = 'days')`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the link and the mapply method !